# Why is my data insertion in my cassandra database so slow?

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka

This is my query if the current data ID is present or absent in the Cassandra database

```
row = session.execute("SELECT * FROM articles where id = %s", [id])
```

Resolved messages in Kafka, then determine whether or not this message exists in the cassandra database if it does not exist, then it should perform an insert operation, if it does exist, it should not be inserted in the data.

```
messages = consumer.get_messages(count=25)

    if len(messages) == 0:
        print 'IDLE'
        sleep(1)
        continue

    for message in messages:
        try:
            message = json.loads(message.message.value)
            data = message['data']
            if data:
                for article in data:
                    source = article['source']
                    id = article['id']
                    title = article['title']
                    thumbnail = article['thumbnail']
                    #url = article['url']
                    text = article['text']
                    print article['created_at'],type(article['created_at'])
                    created_at = parse(article['created_at'])
                    last_crawled = article['last_crawled']
                    channel = article['channel']#userid
                    category = article['category']
                    #scheduled_for = created_at.replace(minute=created_at.minute + 5, second=0, microsecond=0)
                    scheduled_for=(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=5)).replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
                    row = session.execute("SELECT * FROM articles where id = %s", [id])
                    if len(list(row))==0:
                    #id parse base62
                        ids = [id[0:2],id[2:9],id[9:16]]
                        idstr=''
                        for argv in ids:
                            num = int(argv)
                            idstr=idstr+encode(num)
                        url='http://weibo.com/%s/%s?type=comment' % (channel,idstr)
                        session.execute("INSERT INTO articles(source, id, title,thumbnail, url, text, created_at, last_crawled,channel,category) VALUES (%s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (source, id, title,thumbnail, url, text, created_at, scheduled_for,channel,category))
                        session.execute("INSERT INTO schedules(source,type,scheduled_for,id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s) USING TTL 86400", (source,'article', scheduled_for, id))
                        log.info('%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (source, id, title,thumbnail, url, text, created_at, scheduled_for,channel,category))


        except Exception, e:
            log.exception(e)
            #log.info('error %s %s' % (message['url'],body))
            print e
            continue
```

**Edit:**

I have one ID which only has one unique table row, which I want to be like this. As soon as I add different scheduled_for times for the unique ID my system crashes. Add this if len(list(row))==0: is the right thought but my system is very slow after that.

This is my table description:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schedules;

CREATE TABLE schedules (
 source text,
 type text,
 scheduled_for timestamp,
 id text,
 PRIMARY KEY (source, type, scheduled_for, id)
);
```

This scheduled_for is changeable. Here is also a concrete example

```
Hao article 2016-01-12 02:09:00+0800 3930462206848285
Hao article 2016-01-12 03:09:00+0801 3930462206848285
Hao article 2016-01-12 04:09:00+0802 3930462206848285
Hao article 2016-01-12 05:09:00+0803 3930462206848285
```

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Considering that write operations are cheap while read operations may not be, I think the kind of optimization you are trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: @Ralf Ok so what would suggest instead? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Just insert the record again? Or  At the very least do not select * from the table but just the ID. That way you save some network bandwidth. (I think Cassandra still loads the whole row; maybe someone can comment on that.) Depending on your application, selecting every row before inserting has the addtl. downside of diluting Cassandra's caches, degrading read performance for your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `insert if not exists` ?

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/insert_r.html

Comment: Note that `IF NOT EXISTS` also comes with a performance penalty.

Comment: I fully agree, that's a typical case of "read before write" but at least it's easier from the application point of view and maybe more optimised.

Comment: I think it is worse than "just" read before write. For the IF NOT EXIST to work Cassandra has to ensure [consistency across the cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_tunable_consistency_c.html). If you set up the cluster for eventual consistency you loose all the performance benefit of that setup. But I assume IF NOT EXISTS does not mess with the cache contents.

Comment: @CedricH.@ralf I added the example above in my post: I have one ID which only has one unique table row, which I want to be like this. As soon as I add different scheduled_for times for the unique ID our system crashes. Add this if len(list(row))==0: is the right thought but my system is very slow after that. Not sure what to do? Thanks for the help!